# UMDF understanding comparing with Linux Kernel module/driver

Tags: linux, windows, umdf

I have been working on Linux drivers and Kernel modules for Quite some time. Now I need to work on Windows UMDF drivers. Is there any doc explaining UMDF framework comparing with Linux driver model.

I am new to Windows Drivers.

Thanks in advance.

--Jammula.

Answer (score 1):

UMDF stands for **User Mode** Driver Framework.
KMDF stands for **Kernel Mode** Driver Framework. If you want a comparison to Linux kernel development, you probably want to compare KMDF rather than UMDF. There is plenty of documentation on both KMDF and UMDF, you can get a good overview here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463268.aspx

Answer (score 0):

User mode drivers run like any other app and can be restarted when they crash (e.g. a second of blank screen while Windows reloads or updates the video driver), but kernel-mode drivers run inside the kernel and can take down the entire system if they crash.